# Boolean value of objects in Python

Tags: python, boolean

As we know, Python has boolean values for objects: If a class has a `__len__` method, every instance of it for which `__len__()` happens to return 0 will be evaluated as a boolean `False` (for example, the empty list).

In fact, every iterable, empty custom object is evaluated as `False` if it appears in boolean expression.

Now suppose I have a class `foo` with attribute `bar`. How can I define its truth value, so that, say, it will be evaluated to `True if bar % 2 == 0` and `False` otherwise?

For example:

```
myfoo = foo()
myfoo.bar = 3
def a(foo):
    if foo:
        print "spam"
    else:
        print "eggs"
```

so, `a(myfoo)` should print `"eggs"`.

---

<sub>To close questions that are specifically about **debugging an error** caused by using the 3.x-specific approach in 2.x, use [How can I implement conversion to boolean for classes in 2.x? Why doesn't the "__bool__" magic method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558).</sub>

Comment: See also: `__nonzero__()`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### In Python 2, use `__nonzero__`:

Refer to the Python 2 docs for [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).

```
class foo(object):
    def __nonzero__( self) :
        return self.bar % 2 == 0

def a(foo):
    if foo:
        print "spam"
    else:
        print "eggs"

def main():
    myfoo = foo()
    myfoo.bar = 3
    a(myfoo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please refer to other answer for Python 3, this answer applies exclusively to Python 2.

Answer (score 59):

### Python 2.x

Use the [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) magic method. It's called automatically by Python when evaluating an object in a boolean context. It must return a boolean that will be used as the value to evaluate.

E.G :

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, bar) :
        self.bar = bar

    def __nonzero__(self) :
        return self.bar % 2 == 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
     if (Foo(2)) : print "yess !"
```

### Python 3.x

Use [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) instead, in the same way.

Comment: Would you object to further editing this, to prioritize the 3.x answer?