# Evaluation of boolean expressions in Python

Tags: python, object, boolean

What truth value do objects evaluate to in Python?

**Related Questions**

- [Boolean Value of Objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python): Discussion about overriding the way it is evaluated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Any object can be tested for truth
>   value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean
>   operations below. The following values
>   are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.
>
> All other values are considered true
>   -- so objects of many types are always true.
>   Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or `False` for false and 1 or `True` for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations "or" and "and" always return one of their operands.)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

And as mentioned, you can override with custom objects by modifying nonzero.

Comment: Just need to note that in Python 3.0  `__bool__` needs to be overridden instead

Comment: The docs you quote are imprecise (or incomplete); for example, sets are neither sequences nor mappings, yet, when empty, they're also false. I would collapse those two lines (also covering the case of sets) to "any empty **container**".

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: Removed all duplicate infomation with Meder's post

For custom objects in Python < 3.0 `__nonzero__` to change how it is evaluated. In Python 3.0 this is `__bool__` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python/1087166#1087166) by e-satis)

It is important to understand what is meant by evaluate. One meaning is when an object is explicitly casting to a bool or implicitly cast by its location (in a if or while loop).

Another is == evalutation. 1==True, 0==False, nothing else is equal via ==.

```
>>> None==False
False
>>> 1==True
True
>>> 0==False
True
>>> 2==False
False
>>> 2==True
False
```

Finally, for is, only True or False are themselves.

Comment: Custom objects can return True/False for boolean evaluation by implementing __nonzero__