# What is this doing (Python)

Tags: python

I came across a piece of code today that looks like this:

```
class ClassName(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self._vocabulary = None

     def vocabulary(self):
         self._vocabulary = self._vocabulary or self.keys()
         return self._vocabulary
```

What exactly is the line `self._vocabulary = self._vocabulary or self.keys()` doing?

Comment: The first part of your code snippet is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: not quite; I've corrected the class declaration for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A line like this:

```
self._vocabulary = self._vocabulary or self.keys()
```

Is what's called lazy initialization, when you are retrieving the value for the first time it initializes. So if it has never been initialized `self._vocabulary` will be `None` (because the `__init__` method had set this value) resulting in the evaluation of the second element of the `or` so `self.keys()` will be executed, assigning the returning value to `self._vocabulary`, thus initializing it for future requests.

When a second time `vocabulary` is called `self._vocabulary` won't be `None` and it will keep that value.

Comment: Upvoted, but it would be good to clarify that it is the explicit line in `__init__` that sets `self._vocabulary` to `None`, it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: @ncoghlan Thanks for the vote and for the advice. I edited the post, is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, if `self._vocabulary` evaluates to a logical false (e.g. if it's `None`, `0`, `False`, etc), then it will be replaced with `self.keys()`.

The `or` operator in this case, returns whichever value evaluates to a logical true.

Also, your code should look more like this:

```
class Example(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self._vocabulary = None

     def vocabulary(self):
         self._vocabulary = self._vocabulary or self.keys()
         return self._vocabulary

     def keys(self):
         return ['a', 'b']

ex = Example()
print ex.vocabulary()
ex._vocabulary = 'Hi there'
print ex.vocabulary()
```

Comment: `The or operator in this case, returns whichever value evaluates to a logical true.` - This is a little misleading. If `self._vocabulary` evaluates to `False` then `self.keys()` is executed and used for the assignment, whether or not it evaluates as `True` or `False`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452489/evaluation-of-boolean-expressions-in-python/1452500#1452500 for explanation of how things evaluate in boolean expressions.

Comment: @dave - No, lots of other languages have similar operators.  For example, the `||` operator does the same thing in ruby. The equivalent would be `vocabulary ||= keys()` or `vocabulary = (vocabulary || keys())` in ruby. It's common of plenty of other languages besides ruby and python, as well.

Comment: @MattH - I used slightly poor phrasing, but that's _exactly_ what I was saying.  I.e. logical testing, not identity testing whether it `is False`. (Thus the lowercase "logical false" and not the object `False`) Edit: whoops, I misread your comment. Good point...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, the code will not run for a number of reasons. To guess though, I'd say it looks like it would be evaluated as a logical expression, `self._vocabulary` would be evaluated `False` by python as type `None`, and `self.keys()` is a method that would (hopefully) return something to be evaluated as well. Then it's just a logical OR between the two and the result gets put into `self._vocabulary`.