# re.match accept any return value except for empty

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to use re.match function from python. I then have an if statment where if re.match returns anything(indicating that the regex is contained in the string) then it will return what the original string was.Otherwise if it fails I would want to return the word 'failed'.

How would I be able to do this?

Short form: How can an if statement accept any value that isn't a non return.

Comment: Are you looking for `if re.match(...) is None`?  `re.match` returns None if the regex doesn't match.

Comment: This doesn't sound like good design. Your return value has two different roles. I would return a boolean that marks success or failure, and another string for extra data.

Comment: I wasn't aware is none existed, thanks. With regards to the design its not exactly as how I described but I tried to simplify my question so I could get a quick answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use truthiness:

```
if re.match(r'your_regex', your_string):
    return your_string
else:
    return 'failed'
```

If `re.match` returns anything that isn't false-like (`[]`, `{}`, `()`, `0`, `''` `None`, `False`, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452489/evaluation-of-boolean-expressions-in-python)), then  it is evaluated as `True`.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do that. I will go test that out now thank you.

Comment: Note: in general these are also false values: ["instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a __nonzero__() or __len__() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452489/evaluation-of-boolean-expressions-in-python). Though it doesn't matter in this case: re.match returns either None or a Match object that is always true.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about `__nonzero__` and `__bool__` for Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

```
def func(s):
    pattern = "somepattern"
    return s if re.match(pattern, s) else 'failed'
```

Also, returning `"failed"` sounds like a bad idea. What if the input is `"failed"`? Consider using something like `None`.

Comment: both example are equivalent regardless whether the match is empty string or not because re.match() returns either None or Match object (not string).