# Check if object attributes are non-empty python

Tags: python, if-statement

I can check if python list or dictionary are empty or not like this

```
lis1, dict1 = [], {}
# similar thing can be done for dict1
if lis1:
    # Do stuff
else:
    print "List is empty"
```

If I try to do this with my class object, i.e checking if my object attributes are non-empty by typing `if my_object:` this always evaluate to `True`

```
>>> class my_class(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.lis1 = []
...     self.dict1 = {}
... 
>>> obj1 = my_class()
>>> obj1
<__main__.my_class object at 0x10c793250>
>>> if obj1:
...   print "yes"
... 
yes
```

I can write a function specifically to check if my object attributes are non-empty and then call `if obj1.is_attributes_empty():`, but I am more interested in knowing how `if` evaluates the `standard data-types` like `list` and `dict` to `True` or `False` depending on the items they contain or are empty.

If I want to achieve this functionality with my class object, what methods do I need to override or make changes to?

Comment: Try this:  `if obj1.lis1: print "yes"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluation of boolean expressions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452489/evaluation-of-boolean-expressions-in-python)

Comment: Yes I can.... but If their are many attributes ..... it can still be achieved by writing if obj1.attr1 and obj1.attr2 .... and so on.... but I want to avoid this.... I am more interested in knowing how if evaluates standard data-types of python ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement the `__nonzero__` method (or `__bool__` for Python3)

[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**nonzero**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lis1 = []
        self.dict1 = {}

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.lis1 or self.dict1)

obj = my_class()
if obj:
    print "Available"
else:
    print "Not available"
```

Python also checks the `__len__` method for truthiness, but that doesn't seem to make sense for your example.

If you have a lot of attributes to check you may prefer to

```
return any((self.lis1, self.dict1, ...))
```

Comment: The answer is incorrect, since the question is also imposed incorrectly..

Answer (score 3):

The build in [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function makes a useful one-liner for checking if an object has any non-empty attributes. Combine it with [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) and you get the following:

```
def __nonzero__(self):
    return any(vars(self).values())
```

Comment: Why use the `list`?

Answer (score 2):

It is given in the documentation of [Truth value testing for Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) -

> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

For [Python 3.x -](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

According to the definition of your class, if maybe meaningful to define `__len__()` method, which returns the sum of length of the list as well as the dict.Then this method would be called to determine whether to interpret the object as `True` or `False` in boolean context. Example -

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lis1 = []
        self.dict1 = {}
    def __len__(self):
        print("In len")
        return len(self.lis1) + len(self.dict1)
```

Demo -

```
>>> class my_class(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.lis1 = []
...         self.dict1 = {}
...     def __len__(self):
...         print("In len")
...         return len(self.lis1) + len(self.dict1)
...
>>> obj = my_class()
>>> if obj:
...     print("yes")
...
In len
>>> obj.lis1.append(1)
>>>
>>> if obj:
...     print("yes")
...
In len
yes
```

Comment: Wouldlove to hear what is wrong/bad about this answer, that is the only way I can improve the answer.

Comment: It's not inaccurate, but it's possible that the downvoter is evaluating based on usefulness and doesn't think that answers on a duplicate question are useful.

Answer (score 0):

If your class defines (on Py2) [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__), (on Py3) [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) or (on either) [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), then that will be used to evaluate the "truthiness" of objects of that class (if only `__len__` is defined, an instance is truthy when it returns non-zero, and falsy when it returns zero). So, for example, to make your class simply report if it's attributes are non-empty in either Py2 or Py3, you'd add:

```
 def __bool__(self):
     return bool(self.lis1 or self.dict1)
 __nonzero__ = __bool__ # To make it work on Py2 too
```

Alternatively, if your class instances have meaningful lengths, you define:

```
 def __len__(self):
     return len(self.lis1) + len(self.dict1)  # For example; I doubt the length is meaningful in terms of both
```

and get boolean behavior by side-effect of supporting `len(myobject)`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers for using `any()` and `__bool__(self)`, the following code will allow you to check for all of the attributes using list comprehension.

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = []
        self.dict1 = {}

    def __bool__(self):
        check = any([self.__dict__[attr] for attr in self.__dict__.keys()])

        return check

obj1 = my_class()

if obj1:
    print('yes')
```

This code snippet will print nothing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As many answers and duplicate votes suggest, you need to override the `__nonzero__` method. However, from your comment, you also want to avoid enumerating the attributes explicitly. This can be done with a trick like this:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self.attr1 = []
        self.attr2 = {}

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            self._values[name] = value  # keep track of the assigned attributes

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return any(self._values.itervalues())
```

This handles all public attributes that are assigned or modified later on:

```
>>> ex = Example()
>>> bool(ex)
False
>>> ex.attr1.append('data')
>>> bool(ex)
True
>>> ex.attr1.pop()
>>> ex.attr3 = 42
bool(ex)
>>> False
```

Attribute deletion is not handled properly, for that you need to override `__delattr__`.

Answer (score 0):

In python you wouldn't know which attributes to expect if you do not declare them. A standard way to declare attributes is supplied in the dataclass

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class my_class:
   lis1:list = []
   dict1:dict = {}

   def isEmtpy(self)->bool:
      return len(self.lis1)+len(self.dict1)==0
```

To implement a more generic solution you might want to inspect the dataclass source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/dataclasses.py especially the [fields accessor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8bb7fdaee8c19f0311f15dbea7f8eee80a67a50f/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1223)