# Differentiate False and 0

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list with different values, like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'b', None, False, True, 7.0]
```

I want to iterate over it and check that every element is not in list of some forbidden values. For example, this list is `[0, 0.0]`.

When I check `if False in [0, 0.0]` I get `True`. I understand that python casts `False` to `0` here - but how I can avoid it and make this check right - that `False` value is not in `[0, 0.0]`?

Comment: A list will be evaluated as True. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452489/evaluation-of-boolean-expressions-in-python)

Comment: You should check the values individually, your methodology will only at best show you that something failed but won't tell you what, which would be you or your users next question.

Comment: You probably want to rethink the decision that led to a list containing `False` and `0` values that need to be treated differently.

Comment: @chepner actually you're right, bit I got this issue while solving kata from codewars. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To tell the difference between `False` and `0` you may use `is` to compare them. `False` is a singleton value and always refers to the same object.  To compare all the items in a list to make sure they are not `False`, try:

```
all(x is not False for x in a_list)
```

BTW, Python doesn't cast anything here: Booleans are a subclass of integers, and `False` is literally equal to `0`, no conversion required.

Answer (score 12):

You would want to use `is` instead of `==` when comparing.

```
y = 0
print y == False # True
print y is False # False

x = False
print x == False # True
print x is False # True
```

Comment: Good advice, but the original code doesn't contain `==`, it contains `in`. This is not a true answer to the question.

Comment: So the lesson learned is that for comparison of two logicals one should use `is` and `is not` instead of `==`

Comment: @wander95 if you really need to know the difference between `False` and `0`, then yes. `True` and `1` too. Most of the time you don't need the distinction. `in` uses `==` and there's no way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a weird corner case on differentiating between 0 and `False` today. If the initial list contains the numpy version of `False` (`numpy.bool_(False)`), the `is` comparisons [don't work](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5942), because `numpy.bool_(False) is not False`.

These arise all the time in comparisons that use numpy types. For example:

```
>>> type(numpy.array(50)<0) 
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

The easiest way would be to compare using the `numpy.bool_` type: `(np.array(50)<0) is (np.False_)`. But doing that requires a `numpy` dependency. The solution I came up with was to do a string comparison (working as of numpy 1.18.1):

`str(numpy.bool_(False)) == str(False)`

So when dealing with a list, a la @kindall it would be:

`all(str(x) != str(False) for x in a_list)`

Note that this test also has a problem with the string `'False'`. To avoid that, you could exclude against cases where the string representation was equivalent to itself (this also dodges a numpy string array). Here's some test outputs:

```
>>> foo = False
>>> str(foo) != foo and str(foo) == str(False)
True

>>> foo = numpy.bool_(False)
>>> str(foo) != foo and str(foo) == str(False)
True

>>> foo = 0
>>> str(foo) != foo and str(foo) == str(False)
False

>>> foo = 'False'
>>> str(foo) != foo and str(foo) == str(False)
False

>>> foo = numpy.array('False')
>>> str(foo) != foo and str(foo) == str(False)
array(False)
```

I am not really an expert programmer, so there may be some limitations I've still missed, or a big reason not to do this, but it allowed me to differentiate 0 and `False` without needing to resort to a numpy dependency.