# Python list membership with different types

Tags: python

I have a list of Python literals of various types, e.g.:

```
literals = [1, 2, 'a', False]
```

By "literal" I mean any Python object that could be the output of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). I want to write a function `literalInList` to check if some other Python literal `x` is in the `literals` list:

```
x = True
if literalInList(x, literals):  # Should be False.
  print('The literal is in the list.')
```

Notice that I can't just do `x in literals` because the `==` and `in` operators don't check the literal type:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
>>> True in [1, 2, 'a', False]
True
```

So, my best attempt is the following:

```
def literalInList(x, literals):
  return any(x is lit for lit in literals)
```

This is admittedly quite ugly for a simple-sounding task. Is there a more elegant, efficient, or Pythonic way?

Comment: Your list doesn't contain "literals", literals are an aspect of the source code, you used a list literal to create a list that contains various types of objects

Comment: In any case, you want to check for equality and exact type, correct? So, dont accept subclasses? You'll have to write some sort of loop. In any case, membership checking in an (unsorted) list has to be linear, so there is no more efficient way, you just have to write the correct condition. `is` is almost certainly not what you want, unless you are always checking for language-guaranteed singletons. Note, `==` is sensitive to *type*, it just accepts subclasses, and `bool` is an `int`

Comment: Might be useful here [Differentiate False and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640674/differentiate-false-and-0)

Comment: I edited to clarify that "literal" here means any Python object that could be the output of `ast.literal_eval`. I understand that you can't get faster than O(N) worst case time, but efficiency can still be a factor if you consider breaking early or eliminating loops in favor of a built-in operator.

Comment: @pkpnd but what exactly is it that you are trying to check? Your `is` solution checks for *identity*, but that is almost certainly not what you want. Can you specify exactly? Probably you want somthing like `(x == y) and (type(x) is type(y))` using your `any` approach or just a simple loop that breaks early.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you provide an example where that makes a difference over `x is y` for Python literals `x` and `y` as I defined above?

Comment: @pkpnd a quick example, `[] is []` is always false, and `[] == []` is always true. It's the difference between *identity* and *equality*. Read [this answer I wrote a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56247227/why-isnt-is-comparison-used-in-place-of-for-primitive-types/56247404#56247404) for more in-depth discussion on where it is appropriate to use `is` in the way you are *trying* to (that is, `is` for equality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
def literalInList(x, literals):
  def eq_x(y):
    return x == y and type(x) is type(y)
  return any(eq_x(y) for y in literals)

literals = [1, 2, 'a', False]
print(literalInList(True, literals))   # False
print(literalInList(False, literals))  # True
print(literalInList(1, literals))      # True
print(literalInList(1.0, literals))    # False
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I deliberated over that, and decided that `==` was both correct (it is, right?) and more intuitive (for me). :)  Have changed the answer nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: it is also correct. Since everything is an `object`, and `object.__eq__` essentially does an identity comparison, it turns out to be the same thing. ALthough, I suppose you could be working with a class that implements some weird metaclass that breaks the semantic guidlines for class equality, but that's a stretch. It's just more idiomatic, IMO, but it is an issue of style rather than correctness, really.