# Pandas Dataframe - Checking if an entry already exists before entering it, returning False positive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a pandas data frame from a list of objects I've already created. Each entry is added one at a time. In my function, before entering the new object, I want to check whether that value already exists. However when my Data Frame is entry, and I check for that object, it tells me it exists and ignores it.

So I create an empty data frame:

```
clienttable=pd.DataFrame(columns=['ClientNo',
                                               'Last Name',
                                               'Full Name',
                                               'DateofBirth'])
```

I then have 2 entries:

```
client1={'ClientNo':0,'Last Name':'Doe', 'Full Name':'John Doe',
                                   'DateofBirth':12-12-1970}

client2={'ClientNo':1,'Last Name':'Mad', 'Full Name':'Jim Mad',
                                   'DateofBirth':12-1-1983}
```

when I check my clienttable before adding it shows as an empty DataFrame:

```
print(clienttable)    

Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [ClientNo, Last Name, Full Name, DateofBirth]
    Index: []
```

In order to check if the entry already exists I use:

```
if clienttable['ClientNo'].any() == Client1['ClientNo']:
    print("ClientNo is already captured in the Table")
    
else:
     entryadd=pd.DataFrame(data={'ClientNo':[Client1['ClientNo'],
                                        'Last Name':[Client1['Last Name']],
                                        'Full Name':[Client1['Full Name']],
                                   'DateofBirth':[Client1['DateofBirth']])
```

For `Client2, where ClientNo=2`, then this works without issue. It correctly identifies the first time that is is not there and adds it, and then if I try and add it again it tells me it's already captured.

However `for Client1, where ClientNo=1, clienttable['ClientNo'].any() == Client1['ClientNo']` returns True when this is the first entry in the df, so it won't add it.

I'm struggling to understand why when the df is empty, `df['Series'].any()` thinks that an entry with value of 0 is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be to use `is` instead of `==` when you compare `false` and `0` which is probably what you were trying to do. This is because False is actually equal to 0. Please see [Differentiate False and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640674/differentiate-false-and-0)

Your working code:

```
if clienttable['ClientNo'].any() is client1['ClientNo']:
    print("ClientNo is already captured in the Table")
else:
    entryadd = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'ClientNo': [client1['ClientNo']],
        'Last Name': [client1['Last Name']],
        'Full Name': [client1['Full Name']],
        'DateofBirth': [client1['DateofBirth']]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) returns True if anything is present in the series. But you want to check for a particular value. Instead you should to:

```
if Client1['ClientNo'] in clienttable['ClientNo']:
```

This will check correctly.