# How to use `__slots__` with initialization of attributes?

Tags: python, initialization, slots

I read through the main answers on [usage of slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) and it has given me an idea of how and where to use `__slots__` .

Now, I am porting a code from Python 2 to Python 3 which is similar to as following:

```
class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('_fields')
    _fields = set()
```

But this is giving error Python 3 while working fine on Python 2:

**`ValueError: '_fields' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable`.**

I change the code to

```
class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('_fields')
    def __init__(self):
        _fields = set()
```

and it works fine. My query is, is it even the correct change ?

As i got from original code, I guess it is saying that don't use `__dict__` for saving memory or faster access or whatever reason but at the same time is also trying to specify the type of attribute `_field` as set(). Can the change above be the right way to say it or it can have some side effects.

---

**Further Experiments**: 
I experimented further with following variants (on Python 3):

```
import pdb

class A(object):
    a = set()

'''
class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('a')
    a = set()
'''

class C(object):
    __slots__ = ('a')
    def __init__(self):
        a = set()

class D(object):
    def __init__(self):
        __slots__ = ('a')
        a = set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pdb.set_trace()
    x = A(); print(dir(x))
    #y = B()
    z = C(); print(dir(z))
    z1 = D(); print(dir(z1))
```

and it gave following output.

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a']


['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'a']


['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

We can see that only C object shows correct footprint i.e. no `__dict__` and only `__slots__` . Isn't it what ideally we would want ? Any explanation on `__weakref__` would also be helpful.

Also on Python 2, both B and C object show same footprint. Based on that should C be the right way to put it as it is compiling on both Python 2 and 3 as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this is giving error Python 3 while working fine on Python 2:
>
> **`ValueError: '_fields' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable`.**

While you didn't get an error in Python2 at class creation/compile time like in Py3k, if you try to actually set the value of `_fields`, you get `AttributeError: 'C' object attribute '_fields' is read-only`:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   __slots__ = ('_fields')
...   _fields = set()
...
>>>
>>> c = C()
>>> c._fields
set([])
>>> c._fields = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object attribute '_fields' is read-only
>>>
```

Also, see the fourth [note in the slots documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots):

> *`__slots__`* are implemented at the class level by creating descriptors (Implementing Descriptors) for each variable name. As a result, class attributes cannot be used to set default values for instance variables defined by *`__slots__`*; otherwise, the class attribute would overwrite the descriptor assignment.

---

Wrt your modification:

> I change the code to
>
> ```
> class B(object):
>     __slots__ = ('_fields')
>     def __init__(self):
>         _fields = set()
> ```

The modified class B has a `_fields` inside `__init__()`, not `self._fields` so it's just a local variable in init, and not accessible anywhere else in the class. Change that to:

```
 class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('_fields')
    def __init__(self):
        self._fields = set()
```

To correctly initialise `_fields`, do this:

```
 class B(object):
     __slots__ = ('_fields')
     def __init__(self, _fields=None):
         if not _fields:
             self._fields = set()
```

---

Wrt further experimentation:

In class D, `__slots__` is a variable only inside `__init()__`. It's not the (special) class variable `D.__slots__`; or even the instance variable `self.__slots__`. So it has `__dict__`.

Class A has none, so also has `__dict__`.

Class C has `__slots__` correctly.

Comment: Thanks. But did we want to say the following in `__init__` instead
`self._fields = _fields if not None else set()`

Comment: `if not _fields:` checks `_fields` in [boolean context](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452500/1431750). So if `_fields` is `None` then that expression evaluates to `True` and the line `self._fields = set()` gets executed. It could also be done as `if _fields is None: self._fields = set()`. Btw, in the example in your comment, `not None` is always True. You could put it as `self._fields = _fields if _fields is not None else set()` or the more Pythonic `self._fields = _fields if _fields else set()`. _Caveat:_ an empty `set()` evaluates to False so use an appropriate check...

Comment: _Caveat:_ an empty `set()` evaluates to False so use an another check if `set()` is okay but `None` is not. Also, don't intialise function or methods with [mutable types as default argument values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1431750); like `set`, `dict`, `list`, etc. [Another example here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I personally found to solve this issue:

```
class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('_fields')
    _fields: set()

    # Overridden in the derived classes
    def __init__(self, _fields=None):
    # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

(Asssume Python3)

A class attribute does not have to be mentioned in `__slots__`. In other words, a class attribute can be defined even if the class is derived from `object` and its name does not appear in the class' `__slots__`.

The correct way to achieve this in your case is:

```
class B(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'z') # e.g. restrict instance attributes (if wanted)
    _fields = set()             # define the class attribute independently.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a (*stupid?*) idea and I'm really not sure if this is "valid" Python, but it seems to work (quickly tested in Python 3.7.7):

```py
class Slotted:

    __slots__ = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        inst = super().__new__(cls)
        for key, value in inst.__slots__.items():
            setattr(inst, key, value)
        return inst

class Magic(Slotted):

    __slots__ = {
        "foo": True,
        "bar": 17
    }
```

Note that I'm (*wrongly?*) using a `__slots__` dictionary here!

```py
magic = Magic()

print(f"magic.foo = {magic.foo}")
print(f"magic.bar = {magic.bar}")
```

```
magic.foo = True
magic.bar = 17
```

Does anyone know if there are disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Sorry for the duplication but I've just created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492810/is-it-valid-python-to-use-a-slots-dictionary-for-initialization-purposes) from my own answer to get more feedback on the matter.

Comment: Slots defined as dict are meant to contain docstrings for the attribute *not default values!*