# How do I use a Boolean in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

Does Python actually contain a Boolean value? I know that you can do:

```
checker = 1
if checker:
    #dostuff
```

But I'm quite pedantic and enjoy seeing booleans in Java. For instance:

```
Boolean checker;
if (someDecision)
{
    checker = true;
}
if(checker)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Is there such a thing as a Boolean in Python? I can't seem to find anything like it in the documentation.

Comment: Remember... you don't need to declare types when creating a variable. Just 'checker = False' will suffice.

Comment: @Dominic Bou-Samra: "you don't need to declare types"?  That's not quite true.  I think you should say "you cannot possibly declare a type for a variable."

Comment: @S.Lott "you cannot possibly declare a type for a variable"... still not true because you can typecast `some_var = int("1234")`... that line explicitly sets `some_var` => `int`

Comment: @KolobCanyon: That doesn't declare a type for `some_var`. Names don't have types, they have bindings to objects. The object has a type, the name does not. "Declare" usually means "says this name has this type", but even with `some_var = int("1234")` the very next line can be `some_var = "abc"` and now the name is bound to an object of type `str`.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
checker = None 

if some_decision:
    checker = True

if checker:
    # some stuff
```

[Edit]

For more information: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool

Your code works too, since `1` is converted to `True` when necessary.
Actually Python didn't have a boolean type for a long time (as in old C), and some programmers still use integers instead of booleans.

Comment: It is usually simpler to use checker=(some_decision) (e.g. checker=(a<b)), instead of an 'if'.

Comment: this snippet is a bit misleading... you still need to define "checker" before testing it. While OP defines it earlier, in your example checker = None is absolutely necessary or you will get a UnboundLocalError

Comment: Python booleans are integers. `True` and `False` are references to extended `int` objects with overriden `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Comment: Python booleans are not integers; `1 is not True`, but `1 == True`.

Comment: @BallpointBen: they are integers in the common sense of being instances of the `int` type, as shown by `isinstance(True, int)`.

Comment: in the first line, checker = False is more appropriate than using checker = None

Answer (score 95):

The boolean builtins are capitalized: `True` and `False`.

Note also that you can do `checker = bool(some_decision)` as a bit of shorthand -- [`bool`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bool) will only ever return `True` or `False`.

It's good to know for future reference that [classes defining `__nonzero__` or `__len__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) will be `True` or `False` depending on the result of those functions, but virtually every other object's boolean result will be `True` (except for the `None` object, empty sequences, and numeric zeros).

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. As the popular vote has swung to the other answer, I awarded Bastien the 'Accepted Answer'. However yours was most helpful! :)

Comment: bravado: what's the point not accepting the answer you find most helpful? It's totally irrelevant if another answer is upvoted more.

Comment: And the popular vote is also with this answer. Consider changing your vote.

Answer (score 12):

`True` ... and `False` obviously.

Otherwise, `None` evaluates to False, as does the integer `0` and also the float `0.0` (although I wouldn't use floats like that).
Also, empty lists `[]`, empty tuplets `()`, and empty strings `''` or `""` evaluate to False.

Try it yourself with the function `bool()`:

```
bool([])
bool(['a value'])
bool('')
bool('A string')
bool(True)  # ;-)
bool(False)
bool(0)
bool(None)
bool(0.0)
bool(1)
```

etc..

Answer (score 5):

Boolean types are defined in documentation:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

*Quoted from doc:*

> Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true). In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively. The built-in function bool() can be used to cast any value to a Boolean, if the value can be interpreted as a truth value (see section Truth Value Testing above).
>
> They are written as False and True, respectively.

So in java code remove braces, change `true` to `True` and you will be ok :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a `bool` data type (which inherits from `int` and has only two values: `True` and `False`).

But also Python has the `boolean-able` concept for every object, which is used when function `bool([x])` is called.

See more: [object.**nonzero**](http://www.python.org/doc/current/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) and [boolean-value-of-objects-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python).

Comment: x = bool(0) # false &&
x = bool(1) # true

Answer (score 1):

Booleans in python are subclass of integer. Constructor of booleans is `bool`. bool class inherits from int class.

```
 issubclass(bool,int) // will return True
 isinstance(True,bool) , isinstance(False,bool) //they both True
```

`True` and `False` are singleton objects. they will retain same memory address throughout the lifetime of your app. When you type `True`, python memory manager will check its address and will pull the value '1'. for `False` its value is '0'.

Comparisons of any boolean expression to `True` or `False` can be performed using either `is` (identity) or `==` (equality) operator.

```
int(True) == 1
int(False) == 0
```

But note that `True` and '1' are not the same objects. You can check:

```
 id(True) == id(1) // will return False
```

you can also easily see that

```
  True > False // returns true cause 1>0
```

any integer operation can work with the booleans.

```
  True + True + True =3
```

All objects in python have an associated truth value. Every object has `True` value except:

- None
- False
- 0 in any numeric type (0,0.0,0+0j etc)
- empty sequences (list, tuple, string)
- empty mapping types (dictionary, set, etc)
- custom classes that implement `__bool__` or `__len__` method that returns `False` or `0`.

every class in python has truth values defined by a special instance method:

```
 __bool__(self)   OR
 __len__
```

When you call `bool(x)` python will actually execute

```
 x.__bool__()
```

if instance `x` does not have this method, then it will execute

```
 x.__len__()
```

if this does not exist, by default value is `True`.

For Example for `int` class we can define **bool** as below:

```
  def __bool__(self):
      return self != 0
```

for bool(100), `100 !=0`  will return `True`. So

bool(100) == True

you can easily check that `bool(0)` will be `False`. with this for instances of int class only 0 will return False.

another example= bool([1,2,3])

`[1,2,3]` has no `__bool__()` method defined but it has `__len__()` and since its length is greater than 0, it will return `True`. Now you can see why empty lists return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java where you would declare `boolean flag = True`, in Python you can just declare `myFlag = True`

Python would interpret this as a boolean variable