# Are there boolean variables in python 3?

Tags: python, boolean

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boolean in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748641/boolean-in-python)

I cant seem to find references to Boolean variables in Python 3. Are there boolean variables in python?

So for example, how would I do this in python:

```
bool checker;
while(checker = false)
{
//do this
}

...
```

Thanks

Comment: Before the downvotes start to rain down, read this: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: And I could mention this as well: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I'm pretty sure you've managed to save OP a whole bunch of downvotes just by starting your first comment with "Before the downvotes start to rain down".

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as "boolean variable": *variables in Python do **not** have types* as Python is a dynamically typed language.

However, there are "boolean values". The [only] two such boolean values are named by `True` and `False`. The REPL shows:

```
>>> True.__class__
<class 'bool'>
>>> False.__class
<class 'bool'>
```

However, it is often not needed to `== True` or `== False` and is often considered poor practice. In addition, `=` is *always* an assignment operator in Python (and C and Java) and is not an equality operator.

Comment: "variables in Python do not have types". Is this new with Python 3? In 2.7 I can write `foo = False; print type(foo)` and get back `<type 'bool'>`, which leads me to believe that foo has the type bool.

Comment: @Kevin in Python 3 this seems to return `<class 'bool'>` rather than type... but `type(True) is bool` still holds

Comment: @Kevin The *variable* does *not* have a type. The **value** which is the result of evaluating the *variable*, does have a type. (Strongly-typed languages like C, Java, and Haskell attribute types - often with a declaration like `int i` - to variables/bindings and thus limit the values a particular variable can name.)

Comment: @pst: Python is strongly typed.

Comment: @Wooble. It is. However, [Strong-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) (with is the opposite of Weak-typing) is *not related* to [Static-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) (which is the opposite of Dynamic-typing). *Python is Strongly-typed **and** Dynamically-typed*.

Comment: @Wooble Actually, I suppose Strong-typing *could* imply Static-typing in *some* contexts as Static-typing can "specify restrictions on operations involving different data types" (adapted from previous link); however, to do so in the case of Python would be incorrect as Static-typing implies much more.

Comment: @Wooble Oh, I see. I wrote that comment wrong .. it should have been "Statically-typed" way back up there in comment #3. Weak Sauce.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't declare variable types in python. With that in mind, your example is pretty easily translated:

```
checker = False
while not checker:
    # do this
```