# How do I check if a boolean is true or false?

Tags: python

I have a boolean called programRepeated and I need to check if it is true or false with an if / else statement. Is there a way to do this?

```
if programRepeated = True:
            print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert)
            print("")
        elif programRepeated = False:
            print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert - 5)
            print("")
```

Comment: = is assignment. Refer to a tutorial, which should also cover == (comparison). Also, can just use `if x:`, when x is truth’y-false’y.

Comment: A boolean does not need to be compared. That's kind of the point of a boolean. Just use `if programRepeated:`

Comment: Can it ever be anything other than `True` or `False`, and if so, are those other values supposed to be treated as truthy, falsy or neither? I'll note this is *really* basic Python; I'd strongly suggest running through [a tutorial on the language as a whole](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), because learning the basics piecemeal with Stack Overflow question just isn't practical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a Boolean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748641/how-do-i-use-a-boolean-in-python)

Comment: Beware, objects are considered True by default unless they meet the criteria for False: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876672/how-do-i-check-if-a-boolean-is-true-or-false#comment124767447_63876691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean value can go directly into a conditional (if) statement

```
if programRepeated:
```

If `programRepeated` is equal to true, then the code block will execute.

Some notes on your code though: `=` is an assignment operator. If you would like to check if something is equal, please use two equal signs `==`. Your code will throw a syntax error if you try to use `=` in a conditional.

Also, your `elif` should be on the same indentation as the `if` statement, and you can use `else` instead in this case.

```
if programRepeated:
     print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert)
     print("")
else:
     print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert - 5)
     print("")
```

Comment: `=` wouldn't make it always true, this isn't C, and using `=` in a conditional isn't legal code; it would die with a `SyntaxError` during parsing.

Comment: Beware, "an object is considered true unless its class defines either a __bool__() method that returns False or a __len__() method that returns zero, when called with the object".    is_launch_nuke = "Don't launch!!!!"
    launch_nuke() if is_launch_nuke else print("Phew"). Results in nuke lanuched.

Answer (score 0):

well, you don't need to explicitly add the `= True`, you can just do:

```
if programRepeated:
            print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert)
            print("")
        else:
            print("Your balance is : $" , final_balance + cash_insert - 5)
            print("")
```