# Are comparisons really allowed to return numbers instead of booleans, and why?

Tags: python, types, type-conversion, boolean, truthiness

I've found a surprising sentence in the Python documentation under [Truth Value Testing](//docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated.

Relational operators seem to have no excepting statements, so IIUC they could return `0` and `1` instead of `False` and `True` on values of some built-in types (e.g. `7 < 3`), even nondeterministically.

Thus, in order to satisfy a specification requiring of my code to produce values of type `bool` or for defensive programming (whenever that's important), should I wrap logical expressions in calls to `bool`?

Additional question: why does this latitude exist? Does it make things easier somehow for CPython or another implementation?

**EDIT**
The question has been answered and I've accepted, but I'd like to add that in [PEP 285 – Adding a bool type](//peps.python.org/pep-0285/) I've found the following statements:

1. All built-in operations that conceptually return a Boolean result will be changed to return False or True instead of 0 or 1; for example, comparisons, the “not” operator, and predicates like isinstance().
2. All built-in operations that are defined to return a Boolean result will be changed to return False or True instead of 0 or 1. In particular, this affects comparisons (<, <=, ==, !=, >, >=, is, is not, in, not in), the unary operator ‘not’, the built-in functions callable(), hasattr(), isinstance() and issubclass(), the dict method has_key(), the string and unicode methods endswith(), isalnum(), isalpha(), isdigit(), islower(), isspace(), istitle(), isupper(), and startswith(), the unicode methods isdecimal() and isnumeric(), and the ‘closed’ attribute of file objects. The predicates in the operator module are also changed to return a bool, including operator.truth().
3. The only thing that changes is the preferred values to represent truth values when returned or assigned explicitly. Previously, these preferred truth values were 0 and 1; the PEP changes the preferred values to False and True, and changes built-in operations to return these preferred values.

However, PEPs seem to be less authoritative than the documentation (of which the language and library references are the main parts) and there are numerous deviations from PEPs (many of them mentioned explicitly). So until the team updates it, the stronger guarantees of the PEP aren't to be trusted, I think.

**EDIT**
I've reported it on GH [as a Python issue](//github.com/python/cpython/issues/109791)

Comment: the thing is, `bool` objects *are `int` objects*, since `issubclass(bool, int)`. So `isinstance(True, int)` is true. This is because a long time ago Python lacked a dedicated `bool` type. So now, `False == 0` and `True == 1`, and `bool` is just a dedicated subtype of `int`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748641/how-do-i-use-a-boolean-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it is probably important to understand that `bool` objects *are* `int` objects, since `issubclass(bool, int)` is true.

So `isinstance(True, int) and isinstance(False, int)` is true.

Prior to version 2.3 which was released back in 2002, Python lacked a `bool` type. [PEP 285](https://peps.python.org/pep-0285/) was the accepted proposal. Prior to this, these operations would return `0` or `1`. You can read in ["WhatsNew" for 2.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-285-a-boolean-type):

> Most of the standard library modules and built-in functions have been
> changed to return Booleans.

So, I can only surmise that the language was kept to include `0` and `1` while the standard library etc caught up with this change. But by now, I think everything in built-ins and every part of the standard library I've used will return `bool` when the return value is meant to be a boolean.

But keep in mind, from the release notes:

> To sum up `True` and `False` in a sentence: they’re alternative ways to
> spell the integer values `1` and `0`, with the single difference that
> `str()` and `repr()` return the strings `'True'` and `'False'` instead of `'1'`
> and `'0'`.

Comment: Allow me to inquire further in order to ensure I get it all correctly. Since `int` is an immutable type, creation of equal (in the sense of `==`) instances thereof may yield the same or different objects. E.g. `1 is 1` may be true or false, even nondeterministically. On the other hand, `True is 1` is definitely false, but the only difference between them guaranteed to be observable is that `True` and `1` get stringified differently. Right?

Comment: @ByteEater so, `True` and `False` are nowadays language-guaranteed singletons. Note sure if they were at the time the above was written (over 20 years ago). So if you ever want to check if some object is the bool value `True`, you can *always* do `x is True`. This the same for `None` (the only instance of the none-type), and `...` (the only instance of the `ellipsis` type). For other built-in immutable objects, yes, the runtime reserves the right to cache/intern them as it sees fit, and it does. But that should never matter, since those are implementation details

Comment: IOW, `True is True` and `False is False` is always true, guaranteed. same as `None is None` (which is why wheny ou want to check for specifically `None` you use `x is None`)