# Defining "boolness" of a class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, boolean, python-2.x

Why doesn't this work as one may have naively expected?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 3
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.bar > 10

foo = Foo()

if foo:
    print 'x'
else:
    print 'y'
```

(The output is `x`)

Comment: Related: [Boolean value of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087135/674039)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For Python 2-3 compatibility, add a line after the class definition block to alias the method:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...

Foo.__nonzero__ = Foo.__bool__
```

or include the alias directly in the class definition:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __bool__(self):
        ...

    __nonzero__ = __bool__
```

Of course this would also work the other way around, but I think the name `__nonzero__` is just a legacy of the original C-ishness of Python's interpretation of objects as truthy or falsy based on their equivalence with zero.  Just add the statement above and the code will work with regardless of the version of Python (and the `__nonzero__` definition can be dropped when support for 2.x is no longer needed).

Comment: Where would these insertions go? I'm guessing the first could go immediately after the line `return self.bar > 10` (indented 0 spaces) and that the second could go immediately before the line `def __init__(self):` (indented 4 spaces). Is that correct? Or would the second have to go _after_ the `__bool__` definition?

Answer (score 76):

The [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method is used only in Python 3.x. For 2.x, use `__nonzero__`.

Comment: right, strange but true.  good to see they changed implementation to the 'one obvious way to do it'

Comment: @wim: Not too strange.  The `__nonzero__()` method name considerably predates the introduction of the type `bool` in Python.  Before `bool`, the just use the integers `0` and `1`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: You guys had `0` and `1`?  [Dilbert](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1992-09-08/)  ;-)

Answer (score 27):

Because the corresponding special method is called [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) in Python 2, and not [`__bool__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) until Python 3.