# How to implement a if test in a customized class

Tags: python

Is there something like **_*if*_** or **_*not*_** methods implemented in a customized class? So when I instantiate a new class, I can use

```
if myobject:
    return True
```

or

```
if not myobject:
    return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to use instances of your class as boolean values, i.e., some of the instances of your class are truthy and some are falsy, then, in your class, define `__nonzero__` appropriately.

See Section 5.1 in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

By default, saying

```
if myobject:
```

where `myobject` is an instance of some class, will evaluate as if you wrote

```
if True:
```

Defining `__nonzero__()` allows you customize how your objects are used in a boolean context (so to speak).

For Python 3, things are a little different.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558/defining-boolness-of-a-class-in-python).