# Assign class boolean value in Python

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements

If statements in Python allow you to do something like:

```
   if not x:
       print "X is false."
```

This works if you're using an empty list, an empty dictionary, None, 0, etc, but what if you have your own custom class? Can you assign a false value for that class so that in the same style of conditional, it will return false?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining "boolness" of a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558/defining-boolness-of-a-class-in-python)

Comment: @iBug that question is specifically about debugging a version compatibility problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since Python 3, you need to implement the [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method on your class. This should return True or False to determine the truth value:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.val != 0  #This is an example, you can use any condition

x = MyClass(0)
if not x:
    print('x is false')
```

If `__bool__` has not been defined, the implementation will call `__len__` and the instance will be considered True if it returned a nonzero value. If `__len__` hasn't been defined either, all instances will be considered True.

For further reading:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

---

In Python 2, the special method [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) was used instead of `__bool__`.

Comment: Note that it's `__bool__` in Python 3.

Comment: Will this only work if I have () on the end of it? I was hoping for a method that would work whether the item was an empty list, a 0, or an instance of my object that's false. Members of this class, integers, strings, etc, will all be in a list. I need a way to universally test if any of them are false.

Comment: @Kelketek: I fleshed out the example a little. There is no need to put `()` anywhere, it works just like for lists and numbers.

Answer (score 10):

```
class Foo:
     def __nonzero__(self): return False
     __bool__ = __nonzero__ # this is for python3

In [254]: if Foo():
   .....:     print 'Yeah'
   .....: else: print 'Nay'
   .....:
Nay
```

Or, if you want to be ultra-portable, you can define `__len__` only, which will have the same effect in both languages, but that has the (potential) downside that it implies that your object has a meaningful measure of length (which it may not).

This will work for any instance, depending on the actual logic you put in the method.

Comment: "it implies that your object has a meaningful measure of length", true words of wisdom about semantics here.