# Make a python class instance Falsey

Tags: python, class, object

Lets say I am implementing a new type of list.

List types in python evaluate to False if they are not populated. How could I get my class to have this sort of behaviour?

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __something__(self):
        return self.value
```

So then;

```
if Example(True):
    print "Yay!"

if not Example(False):
    print "Yay!"
```

The ideal return would be two lines of "Yay!"

Comment: [Assign class boolean value in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787890/assign-class-boolean-value-in-python)

Comment: @gongzhitaao - Wow.  You found/posted a duplicate in less than a minute.  Talk about being on the ball.

Comment: @just luck to find the right google keyword :)

Comment: Thanks for that :P I did try to search, but I guess I just chose the wrong words.