# In Python, Return “None” instead of creating new instance if wrong parameters are given

Tags: python, class, instance

when creating instance of a class, if wrong parameters are given. how do I　NOT to create a new instance and return the reference, but instead just return a "None"

here is my application:
Because it is allowed sometime. My application is to build trees from a list of integers. I want to use None in the list to represent a leaf. so I just want to return a None instead of a empty tree node.

Comment: Why do you want to do that instead of raising an exception?

Comment: Because it is allowed sometime. My application is to build trees from a list of integers. I want to use None in the list to represent a leaf. so I just want to return a None instead of a empty tree node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/17332994/1735796) to [Python `__init__` return failure to create](//stackoverflow.com/questions/17332929/python-init-return-failure-to-create).

Basically, you can use `__new__` to accomplish what you want, but really, the Pythonic way of doing this would be to throw an exception. Arguably, the Pythonic way would be to have a simpler `__init__` method that is simply an initialization and not something that can fail at all.

Answer (score 7):

Most of these answers aren't right. The appropriate way to do this is to validate your arguments in the class's `__new__` method, and return `None` if validation fails or `ins` if validation succeeds.

Here's what you're looking for:

```
import pytest # for testing


class ValidatedModel:
    def __init__(self, *, name=None):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def _validate(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            assert not args
            assert list(kwargs.keys()) == ['name']
            assert len(kwargs['name']) > 5 and len(kwargs['name']) < 10
        except AssertionError:
            return False
        return True

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._validate(*args, **kwargs):
            return super().__new__(cls)


class TestValidatedModel:
    def test_success(self):
        vm = ValidatedModel(name='william')
        assert isinstance(vm, ValidatedModel)

    def test_kwarg_fail_unexpected_kwarg(self):
        vm = ValidatedModel(name='william', gender='M')
        assert vm is None

    def test_kwarg_fail_name_length_short(self):
        vm = ValidatedModel(name='bill')
        assert vm is None

    def test_kwarg_fail_name_length_long(self):
        vm = ValidatedModel(name='william johnson')
        assert vm is None

    def test_no_name_kwarg(self):
        vm = ValidatedModel()
        assert vm is None
```

Obviously you can replace the `_validate` method with your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the object to `None`, I assume that in other places of your code, you are going to test for the object being `None` (before assuming it's a genuine Node). So maybe, a custom `__nonzero__` method could do the trick (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787890/assign-class-boolean-value-in-python)), eg:

```
class MyNode():
  def __init__(self, ...):
    self.ok = False
    if ...genuine node...:
      self.ok = True
      ...
  def __nonzero__(self):
    return self.ok


node = MyNode(...)
if node:
  ...node code...
else:
  ...leaf code...
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parameters are present create class instance else None Object

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs or args:
            return super().__new__(cls)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **init**, in case of exception just put a return. That will do the trick.

```
class MyTest(object):
    def __init__(self, * args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Your code goes here
        except:
            print "No donuts buddy"
            return
            # An  empty return will return a None
```

In case you wish to instantiate another class or any such advanced maneuvers, you need to write a __ new __ constructor in your class instead of doing it in the __ init __ constructor.

Answer (score -4):

you can use the isinstance(object, class) function inside an if statment to check each parameter
for example:

```
if not isinstance(num, int):
    return None
```

Comment: But returning `None` from within an `__init__` still allows the construction to go forward. While it’s true that this is a valid way to check that arguments are certain types inside a function or method (though I’m not sure it’s wise to be checking *types* when you could be checking *supported behavior*), it’s not useful inside `__init__`.