# Returning the truthiness of a variable rather than its value?

Tags: python, string, boolean, truthiness

Consider this code:

```
test_string = 'not empty'

if test_string:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I know I could construct a conditional expression to do it:

```
return True if test_string else False
```

However, I don't like testing if a boolean is true or false when I'd rather just return the boolean. How would I just return its truthiness?

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8205558/674039

Comment: I don't see any difference, an empty string will evaluate to False and vice versa for a non empty string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I used a string for a simple example. Usually I can get away with just using the object. My actual code is checking if a service is running. If no response is given, I want to return False. If I do get a response though, I don't actually care what the value is. The fact I got a response is enough. The problem is I don't want to provide the response to my user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool):

```
return bool(test_string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> bool('abc')
True
>>> bool('')
False
>>>
```

Comment: Fast answer :). Vote up

Comment: I did some more research and found a book that says truthiness is checked by first calling `__nonzero__`, and if that is undefined it then calls `__len__`. I'm guessing this is the same way bool() works, right?

Comment: It depends on what version of Python you are using.  In Python 2.x, `bool()` will call `__nonzero__` or, if that is not implemented, `__len__`.  If neither of those are implemented, then it will return `True`.  Here is a [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__). In Python 3.x however, `bool()` calls `__bool__` first, which is a replacement for `__nonzero__`.  For a reference, see the link in my answer.