# Chain overloaded comparison operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to do something like this:

```
MyClass > 200 < 400
```

The class implements the `__gt__()` and `__lt__()` methods and they both return `self`.

```
class MyClass:

    ...

    def __gt__(self, value):
        DoCompareStuff(self, value)
        return self

    def __lt__(self, value):
        DoCompareStuff(self, value)
        return self

   ...
```

It will do the first evaluation, `MyClass > 200`, but never performs the second, `MyClass < 400`. It seems like Python is doing something with the return value like making it `True` or `False`. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Why exactly do they return self? The functions should return true or false, based on the outcome of comparison. This way, the outcome is always true, unless you've defined the boolean value of your class to be something else.

Answer (score 4):

Operator chaining for comparisons (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)) means that

```
MyClass > 200 < 400
```

is actually evaluated as:

```
(MyClass > 200) and (200 < 400)
```

therefore no comparison between `MyClass` and `400` is ever made. Instead, you want:

```
200 < MyClass < 400
```

which is evaluated as:

```
(200 < MyClass) and (MyClass < 400)
```

For a simpler example:

```
>>> class Demo(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other


>>> demo = Demo(250)
>>> 200 < demo < 400
True
```

**Note** that the `__lt__` and `__gt__` implementations here have a Boolean return (`True` or `False`), rather than returning `self` (which will lead to unexpected behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this code doesn't make sense:

```
MyClass > 200 < 400
```

As it expands to:

```
MyClass > 200 and 200 < 400
```

Which resolves to:

```
MyClass > 200
```

Secondly, Python has a strong concept of ["truthiness"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116883/is-truthiness-a-legitimate-programming-term) when it comes to boolean values. Which means in essence, anything that is not zero-ish is "true".

Lastly, when you have this code:

```
def __gt__(self, value):
    DoCompareStuff(self, value)
    return self
```

Since `self` will be an object of some type, it will *always, **always***<sup>*</sup> be true. For example both of these will evaluate to true, because you are returning `self`:

```
10 < MyClassInstance
10 > MyClassInstance
```

---

<sup>* sometimes, [except when you implement the `__bool__` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558/defining-boolness-of-a-class-in-python). (Thanks @wim)</sup>

Comment: _always_, ***always***, except [sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8205558/674039)..

Comment: @wim Oh my gosh! Thats awesome!