# How can I print the Truth value of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, output

In Python, variables have truthy values based on their content. For example:

```
>>> def a(x):
...     if x:
...         print (True)
... 
>>> a('')
>>> a(0)
>>> a('a')
True
>>> 
>>> a([])
>>> a([1])
True
>>> a([None])
True
>>> a([0])
True
```

I also know I can print the truthy value of a comparison without the if operator at all:

```
>>> print (1==1)
True
>>> print (1<5)
True
>>> print (5<1)
False
```

But how can I print the `True` / `False` value of a variable? Currently, I'm doing this:

```
print (not not a)
```

but that looks a little inelegant. Is there a preferred way?

Comment: `bool` is the way to go, but I like the `not not` hack :)

Comment: @CraigBurgler -- the `not not` hack is used a lot in Javascript... `!!whatever` is a pretty standard idiom for "give me the 'boolean-ness' of whatever".  I've never seen it in Python though :-)

Comment: there is also `True if a else False` ... but use bool :)

Comment: @mgilson: It could be marginally useful in cases where you want to microoptimize the global lookup and function call, since [`not not x` is a bit faster than `bool(x)`](http://ideone.com/CFYruw), but I've never actually seen it in practice. Cases where that kind of microoptimization would matter are pretty rare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the builtin `bool` type.

```
print(bool(a))
```

Some examples from the REPL:

```
>>> print(bool(''))
False
>>> print(bool('a'))
True
>>> print(bool([]))
False
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a name for this inherent truthyness to variables - so I could more easily search next time?

Comment: @Tim -- Hmmm ... No "names" are really coming to mind.  In this case, I might have asked Google how to construct a boolean from an instance of something.

Comment: I wondered that too.  If you ever find it, please rename ["boolness"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558/defining-boolness-of-a-class-in-python) question ..

Comment: @Tim The name may be `truth value` as per the first section of the `Built-in Types` doc: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: @CraigBurgler In that case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777 is Related but not a duplicate - as it is not asking about printing it. Leaving it here for the sidebar.

Comment: Always important to note: `bool([False])==True`

Comment: @IanAuld Yes, it's a non-empty list. Just as `bool([0])` and `bool(['']` are `True`.