# How to test if a value is falsy in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Javascript, there is == operator to test if a value is falsy:

```
'' == false // true
```

In Python, == corresponds to === in Javascript, which is an exact equation (value & type).

**So how to find out if a value is Falsy in Python?**

Comment: Use False instead of false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I print the Truth value of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604780/how-can-i-print-the-truth-value-of-a-variable)

Answer (score 6):

You can obtain the *truthiness* of a value, by using the `bool(..)` function:

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('foo')
True
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(None)
False
```

In an `if` statement, the *truthiness* is calculated implicitly. You can use the `not` keyword, to invert the truthiness. For example:

```
>>> not ''
True
>>> not 'foo'
False
>>> not 1
False
>>> not None
True
```

Answer (score 2):

To get implicit conversion you can just use `not` - or (for "truthy") just use the variable in place:

```
if not None:
    print('None')

if not False:
    print('False')

if not '':
    print('empty string')

if not 0:
    print('zero')

if not {}:
    print('empty/zero length container')

if 'hello':
    print('non empty string, truthy test')
```

Comment: if not False: print("False") ?

Answer (score 0):

What worked was using ternary:

```
True if '' else False # False
```

More verbose than in Javascript, but works.

Comment: Or just `bool('')`.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho this question is old, but there is a `not not` (kinda hacky), but this is the faster than `bool(..)` and probably the fastest that's possible, you can do it by:

```
print(not not '')
print(not not 0)
print(not not 'bar')
```

Output:

```
False
False
True
```