# Correct condition for file reading using readline() in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand the code below works fine. Reading the while loop documentation in Python, they say that while expression should be True or False and that makes sense.

Now the `readline()` function returns string. So how this while loop works that way?

```
with open(datafile, "r") as f:
        line = f.readline();
        while line :
            print line
            line = f.readline()
            data.append(line)
        print line
    return data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

When used in a boolean context, many objects resolve to `True` or `False`, in this case that includes an empty string.  Numeric zero, an empty tuple, list, set, and dictionary are also `False`.

A class can decide itself when/if an object is `True` or `False` by providing a `__bool__` method (or `__nonzero__` in Python 2).  Although sometimes truth is not relevant for an object.

See also [Defining "boolness" of a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205558/defining-boolness-of-a-class-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

A string in Python that is equal to `""` evaluates to `False`, while any string that is not blank will evaluate to `True`.

```
#Evaluates to False
print(bool(""))

#Evaluates to True
print(bool("A String"))
```

In the loop you have specified, if there was a line that was successfully read, the string `line` will not be blank, and thus will evaluate to `True`. Once there is a line that didn't read in a string, the string `line` will be set to `False` and the loop should exit.