# How do I add `active` class for my current list group?

Tags: python, django

This is a sample of my current list-group:

[image]

Since `Python Flow Control` link on side bar is active, I want it to be highlighted by adding a CSS `active` class.

I think I can do that using current URL of the page, being in `Python Flow Control` page the current URL looks like `http://localhost:8000/python/python-flow-control/` and in template if I type `{{ request.path }}` it would return `/python/python-flow-control/`.

Using URL I tried this approach but it didn't work:

```
<div class="list-group">
{% for sub_cat in sub_cats %}
    <a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorials' sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug sub_cat.sub_cat_slug %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if request.path == '/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug}}/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_slug}}/' %} active {% endif %}">
    {{ sub_cat.sub_cat_title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I added `{% if request.path == '/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug}}/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_slug}}/' %} active {% endif %}` to check if the current URL matches with url of the current clicked link and if it matches add css `active` class.

However, this had no effect. It didn't throw any error and didn't work either.

edit: I tried this, it didn't work either

```
{% url '{{request.path}}' category='python' sub_cat='python-introduction' as target %}

{% if target %}
    <div class="bg-secondary">active</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your solution should work.

Comment: the question is how do I add active class to current clicked link of side bar? I shown my approach, it didn't throw any error and didn't work either.

Comment: `{% if request.path == '/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug}}/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_slug}}/' %} active {% endif %}` are there any errors in here?

Comment: https://github.com/basirpayenda/tutorial-website

this is its link on github, i hope someone looks and help me with this

Comment: Have you checked that the request.path is really what you expect, including slashes? I'd recommend using the url resolver to generate path, everywhere in your code (template and else). code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve and template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Yes, request.path works as expected, assuming i clicked on `Python Introduction` link, the url will then look like this `/python/python-introduction/` and `request.path` returns the very same url `/python/python-introduction/`.

according to above example `sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug` returns `Python` and `sub_cat.sub_cat_slug` returns `python-introduction`, I think the only problem remains in here is with slashes. The slashes are placed wrong. or there is other problem with it.

Comment: If it is "Python" instead of "python" it's casing. `==` is a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: I apologize it is 'python'. Can you please take a look to it. I just added a github link? since last night I am trying different ways nothing seems to work. It would be a great help. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added {% if request.path == '/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug}}/{{sub_cat.sub_cat_slug}}/' %} active {% endif %} to check if the current URL matches with url of the current clicked link and if it matches add css active class.
>   However, this had no effect. It didn't throw any error and didn't work either.

Of course not, cf my answer to your (almost duplicate) other question.

> edit: I tried this, it didn't work either
>
> {% url '{{request.path}}' category='python' sub_cat='python-introduction' as target %}
>
> {% if target %}

Of course not. First because the first argument to `{% url %}` is the url's name, not `request.path` - which you should know since it's already in your original snippet:

```
<a href="{% url 'tutorials:tutorials' sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug sub_cat.sub_cat_slug %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
```

and then because `{% if target %}` only [tests the boolean value of `target`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python).

The simple obvious answer is:

```
<div class="list-group">
{% for sub_cat in sub_cats %}
    {% url 'tutorials:tutorials' sub_cat.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug sub_cat.sub_cat_slug as sub_cat_url %}
    <a href="{{ sub_cat_url }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {% if request.path==sub_cat_url %} active {% endif %}">
    {{ sub_cat.sub_cat_title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: @Noor you're welcome - now may I suggest you read this ? : https://www.google.com/search?q=programming+by+accident