# Having Trouble With Discount Calculator

Tags: python, if-statement

Having trouble understanding what's wrong with my code. It keeps printing out the additional_discount value regardless of the input for student_status. [seen here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXsee.png)

```
def discount(x):
    return x * .9

def additional_discount(x):
    return discount(x) * .95

og_price = float(input("Please enter your current price in dolalrs: "))
student_status = str(input("Are you a student? "))

if student_status == "Yes" or "yes"
    print("Your price is ", additional_discount(og_price))
elif student_status == "No" or "no":
    print("Your price is ", discount(og_price))
else:
    print("I'm sorry, that is an invalid response")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Stackoverflow encourages including code not links to code so others can easily experiment.

Comment: Your problem is you are incorrectly comparing a value to multiple values (i.e. student_status == "Yes" or "yes" is incorrect).  Use if student_status == "YES" or student_status == "yes".  Or more simply: if student_status.lower() == "yes"

Comment: Having had a very quick look at your code, you only specify half of the or statement - ‘or ‘yes’’ rather than or x == ‘yes’. Just or ‘yes’ will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your if-condition:

```
if student_status in ['Yes', 'yes']:
  do something
elif student_status in ['No', 'no']:
  do
```

The statement you use is `if student_status == 'Yes' or 'yes'`. It means `student_status == 'Yes'` or `'yes'`. The boolean value for `'yes'` is `True`, so the condition always holds.

You can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087135/boolean-value-of-objects-in-python) for the boolean value of python objects.

Comment: Thank you for the great response. I don't know the classes yet but want to ask why "Yes" gets a Boolean value of true. Is it because everything has a default value of true unless it goes against a specified condition?

Comment: A string object is true unless it is an empty string ``''``.